# ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter laggy ONLY when long text

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter, lag

I have a `ListView` displaying elements containing text only (a title, a main content and a date). Text is stored in a sqlite database which I query with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and then bind to the `ListView`. The main content text is displayed on 4 lines only (I ellipsize it).
I also use a `CursorLoader` and `ViewHolder` to cache data.
There're no problems at all when my main content text is short. But when it is much longer, scrolling is laggy as hell.

I figured out it's maybe loading the long text from the database that's taking so much time.
Is there a way to only query the text needed from the database (query only the beginning of the text, ie the 4 first lines needed to be displayed)?
Or maybe I shouldn't be using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`? Is it better to use this with a database query?

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT: Also, I noticed that if all the texts are the same (even if they are very long), there'll be no lag

EDIT2: Is it because I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter with CursorLoader? Maybe I should be using a custom CursorAdapter instead?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new column with only the beginning of the text? (you need to find out how many characters is needed to fit on 4 lines). To show the list, you can use this column in your projection.

Comment: Hi Bismark Ito, I thought about that, but how can I know how many characters to store in that new column? If a user has a bigger screen size, there won't be enough text (for example on a tablet).

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it's something with the size of the text in the TextView, not the  Adapter or the disk read. To solve it, I did a bit of a hack by taking the substring of 400 characters before setting it to a TextView.